# Keras Lambda layer error: did not return a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am using Lambda to create a self attention layer, but it raise an error that the output of lambda layer is not a tensor.

My code:

```
def selfAttention(x):
    # input shape [None, n_window_sizes, n_hidden]
    temp_transpose = K.transpose(x) 
    inputs_transpose = K.permute_dimensions(temp_transpose, [2, 0, 1]) # [None, n_hidden, n_window_sizes]
    temp_weights = tf.matmul(x, inputs_transpose)
    weights = tf.nn.softmax(temp_weights)
    output = tf.matmul(weights, x)
    return output
```

I call Lambda function as below:

```
attention_input = K.stack([lstm[0], lstm[1], lstm[2]], axis = 1)
l_attention = Lambda(selfAttention)(attention_input)
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: it says that the output of Lambda is type: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.layers.core.lambda'>, and required input of next layer is tensor

Comment: SOLVED!! Fixed with use lambda wrap for K.stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lambda function to wrap K.stack as follow will solve the problem.

```
 attention_input = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x[0], x[1], x[2]], axis = 1))([lstm[0], lstm[1], lstm[2]])
```